# What about two sets when the boundary of one is included in the boundary of the other

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hi everyone: Suppose $V$ is a bounded open set and $F$ a closed set with non-empty interior, both in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. If the boundary of $V$ is included in the boundary of $F$, can we conclude that  $V$ is included either in $F$ or in the complement of $F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For k = 1, let V = (0,4), F = [0,1] union [3,4] which can be extended for k > 1.  If V and F were simply connected, would the conjecture hold?